# In which path should I install socket.io for node.js programming

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In which path should I install socket.io for node.js programming. should I install it in the same path as that of node.js ?

Comment: [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). The location of `socket.io` should follow the guidance described there.

Answer (score 4):

Your best approach is to use `npm` to install your packages:

```
npm install socket.io
```

This will install it in the folder where you run it for that specific project.

If you want it to be installed globally for all your projects:

```
npm install -g socket.io
```

Comment: +1, you should almost _always_ include Socket.IO as a dependency in your package.json and install it in your local `node_modules` folder. Check out http://nodecasts.net/episodes/4-packages-and-npm for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I installed node.js.(It is in c:\drive) After that I opened Node.js command prompt to load socket.io. It's default path in my machine is G:\. So it got installed there as G:\node_modules\socket.io. Is this a problem.? Should I have it in c:\ drive itself.

Comment: @Muthukumar: Like I said, the best approach is to install it using `npm`. That way you don't have to worry about path headaches. On top of that getting into the habit of using `npm` is always a good thing ;)

Comment: @robbrit I actually did install using npm. Thanks. From ur statement, I assume that socket.io installation is not a problem for me.

Comment: so, (in case of windows) C:\Windows\system32 is the best folder for socket.io?, because by default npm will install it there

Comment: Usually it's easiest to just use the defaults. That's weird that it would install it there though, usually it just installs to the local folder.